# Issue in running async function call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await

I am making an api call and using the filetype variable in another function tapplace but the function is sometimes running and sometimes not can anyone help understand and clear the issue I guess it is because of the async behavior of fetch API call

```
var query = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
var slug_url = query.split("?id=");
slug_url = `${slug_url}`.replace("id=", "");

let filetype = '';

fetch("https://api.morkshub.xyz/api/get_node/" + slug_url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    data.data.map((obj) => {
      var newAssets = obj.assets;
      newAssets.map((newObj) => {
        if (newObj.type == "content") {
          const gltfUrl = `url(${ApiAssetUrl + newObj.assets})`;
          content = ApiAssetUrl + newObj.assets;
          if(gltfUrl.includes(".glb")){
            filetype = 'model'
          }else if(gltfUrl.includes(".jpg") || gltfUrl.includes(".png") || gltfUrl.includes(".png")){
            filetype = 'image';
          }else if(gltfUrl.includes(".mp4") || gltfUrl.includes(".m4v")){
            filetype = 'video'
          }
          console.log(filetype)
         
          tapplace();
        }
      });
    });
  });

async function tapplace(){
const tapPlaceCursorComponent = {
  init() {
    
    console.log("hellooooooo" , filetype)
    let model;
    if(filetype == "image"){
      model = document.getElementById('entityimage');
    } else if(filetype == "video"){
      model = document.getElementById('entityvideo');
    } else{
      model = document.getElementById('model');
    }
    this.model = model;
    this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    this.camera = document.getElementById('camera');
    this.threeCamera = this.camera.getObject3D('camera');
    this.ground = document.getElementById('ground');
    this.cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');
    let hasPlacedModel = false;
    // 2D coordinates of the raycast origin, in normalized device coordinates (NDC)---X and Y
    // components should be between -1 and 1.  Here we want the cursor in the center of the screen.
    this.rayOrigin = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
    this.cursorLocation = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      if (hasPlacedModel !== true) {
        hasPlacedModel = true;
        this.model.setAttribute('position', this.el.object3D.position);
        this.model.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
        this.model.play();
        hasPlacedModel = true;
        // Remove ghosted model from scene after model is placed
        this.cursor.parentNode.removeChild(this.cursor);
        // Add raycaster to camera
        this.camera.setAttribute('raycaster', 'objects: .cantap');
      }
    });
  },
  tick() {
    // Raycast from camera to 'ground'
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.rayOrigin, this.threeCamera);
    const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.ground.object3D, true);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      const [intersect] = intersects;
      this.cursorLocation = intersect.point;
    }
    this.el.object3D.position.y = 0.1;
    this.el.object3D.position.lerp(this.cursorLocation, 0.4);
    this.el.object3D.rotation.y = this.threeCamera.rotation.y;
  },
};
AFRAME.registerComponent('tap-place-cursor', tapPlaceCursorComponent);
}
```

I want to set the value of filetype variable from the api and want to use it below in the tapplacecursor component but the function is not working correctly

Comment: Why is `tapplace` an `async function` in the first place? You never `await` ANYWHERE in your code

Comment: oh that's a mistake I modified the code and left the async part however even after removing the async it is still not working

Comment: is there anywhy to call the function after the api call soi can use the data from the api

Comment: If you have multiple assets, `newAsssets.map(,.,.,.)` sets global variables from the last asset (after having set them to previous assets beforehand). What is it supposed to do by design? Try to avoid using `.map` instead of `forEach` when it does nothing more.

Comment: First of, makes no sense to use `.map()` if you're not `return`ing a new Array. Use `.forEach()` - if that's what you want - and that's to just iterate over your arrays.